# SSH: User name of the remote machine's user?

Tags: ssh, bash, ubuntu-18.04

I need to run a script from my local machine on a remote server via SSH. One of the operations involves `chown` and for that I need to have a programatic access to the server's user name (I am looping through a couple of servers)

But when using `whoami` for the `chown` argument I get the username of my user on the local machine that is SSHing in.

If I check with simple whoami it gives the remote user but I cannot capture it into a variable.

How to get the remote user name?

```
ssh $server << EOF
  pwd
  whoami
  rsync /some/stuff ./dump
  chown `whoami`:`whoami` ./dump
EOF
```

Comment: The problem is lack of proper quoting and the will result in the back-tick escaped ` and variables  commands getting executed on your workstation rather than on the remote server. 

I think you should surround the start of heredoc statement (the `EOF`) with single quotes `'` to prevent that variable expansion

Comment: @HBruijn Ah yes! Thanks. This is a way to capture `me="\`whoami\`"`
and it can be used in the commands as `\$me`.